# Nothing happening after hitting submit button on form

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

Nothing is happening after hitting the submit button on my form. Not an error nothing happens. I'm using `node.js` with express and nodemailer to submit my form. Most of the questions related to this are `php` and aren't in this area. Any help you give would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my `server.js`:

```
app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    //Check if all required fields are filled                                                                                                                                       
    if (!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.message) {                                                                                                                   
        res.render('contact', {                                                                                                                                                     
            title: 'Contact',                                                                                                                                                       
            err: true,                                                                                                                                                              
            page: 'contact',                                                                                                                                                        
            type: 'empty',                                                                                                                                                          
            body: req.body.message,                                                                                                                                                 
            name: req.body.name,                                                                                                                                                    
            email: req.body.email,                                                                                                                                                  
            msg: 'Thanks.',                                                                                                                                                         
            description: 'Email is successful'                                                                                                                                      
        });                                                                                                                                                                         
        return;                                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                    
    //Set up smtp mailer                                                                                                                                                            
    smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({                                                                                                                                        
        service: 'Gmail',                                                                                                                                                           
        auth: {                                                                                                                                                                     
            user: "madeforgoggl@gmail.com",                                                                                                                                        
            pass: ""                                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                    
    });                                                                                                                                                                             
    //Fill mail options                                                                                                                                                             
    mailOpts = {                                                                                                                                                                    
        from: req.body.name + '&lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;', // grab form data from the requet body                                                                              
        to: 'madeforgoggle@gmail.com',                                                                                                                                              
        subject: 'Website contact',                                                                                                                                                 
        text: req.body.message + '  || NAAM:' + req.body.name + ' || EMAIL:' + req.body.email                                                                                       
    };                                                                                                                                                                              
    smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, info) {                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                    
        //Email not sent                                                                                                                                                            
        if (error) {                                                                                                                                                                
            //console.log(error)                                                                                                                                                    
            res.render('contact', {                                                                                                                                                 
                title: 'Contact',                                                                                                                                                   
                page: 'contact',                                                                                                                                                    
                type: 'error',                                                                                                                                                      
                description: 'Email not successful'                                                                                                                                 
            });                                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                           
        // Yay!! Email sent                                                                                                                                                         
        else {                                                                                                                                                                      
            res.render('contact', {                                                                                                                                                 
                title: 'Contact',                                                                                                                                                   
                page: 'contact',                                                                                                                                                    
                type: 'success',                                                                                                                                                    
                description: 'Email successful'                                                                                                                                     
            });                                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                           
    });                                                                                                                                                                             
});
```

Here is my form- Changed the button action to a input submit because I thought that was the problem:

```
<form action="/contact" id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="yourname" type="text"name="name" placeholder="name" class="form-control" required size="40" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="yourcompany" type="text" name="company" placeholder="company" class="form-control" required size="40" />                             <
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="youremail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" class="form-control" required size="40" />                              <
                                    </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea id="yourmessage" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="MESSAGE" required size="40" rows="10"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">
                                        Send Message
                                    </input>
                                                                           

                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                   I've been working on this since 4 am and can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: have you checked the POST request is made by looking at network tab in the browser console?

Comment: Yes just checked also looked in the console nothing has been happening. Forgive my ignorance

Comment: do you have javascript attached to the form or button?

Comment: btw, the submit button is not valid, it should be: `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" value="Send Message"/>
`

Comment: Thanks! No javascript attached to the button I followed this tutorial:
https://www.lucius.digital/en/blog/headless-drupal-simple-contact-form-nodejs

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Here is a new tutorial I'm following: http://www.prowaretech.com/Computer/JavaScript/NodejsContactForm

This does have a script on the html side but when I click the button nothing happens same response.

Comment: you need to do some debugging, as said check network if its not doing the post request then something wrong clientside, if it is but its hanging then its something serverside which if its an error it would show on the console or do you mean the *does nothing* means it's not sending? you're not really clear on that. did you change the submit button? as clicking on the above Send Message wouldn't do anything because it's not a valid tag <inputs end with /> they dont have </input>'s like a button would, also you not closing `</form>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223912/discussion-between-lebaneseblonde252-and-lawrence-cherone).